# How find all events including recurring, for today?

Tags: android, google-calendar-api

I have this situation. Lets say that today is **03.12**

```
| 01.12 | 02.12 | 03.12 | 04.12 |
|       | rec#1 | rec#1 | rec#1 |
|       |       | rec#2 | rec#2 |
| rec#3 |       | rec#3 | rec#3 |
|       |       | evt#1 |       |
```

**rec#1** is recurring event which starts on 02.12. and its everyday.
**rec#2** is recurring event which starts on 03.12 (today) and its everyday.
**rec#3** is recurring event which starts on 01.12 and its every 2nd day.
**evt#2** is an simple event which for one day 03.12 (today)

Now I want to query Calendar Provider for all events for today.
So I put in where clause condition for 
CallendarContract.Events.DTSTART **BETWEEN** **03.12 00:00** AND **03.12 23:59**
But than I receive only rec#2 and evt#1
rec#2 because its first occurrence of this recurring event. And evt#1 because it fits query.

**My questions is:**

This is possible to receive form Calendar Provider all events which occur for given scope? For this example I want get as well rec#1 and rec#3

Now I have an idea to get all recurring events and calculate them in java but I want do that in better way. I don't want to load unnecessary recurring events and waste resources for calculating if this event fits or not.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think what you are looking for is the instances table: http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/providers/calendar-provider.html#instances